# Print an element in a list based on a condition

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists which contain a first name, last name, and points scored.

```
list1 = [['david', 'carter', 6], ['chris', 'jenkins', 0], ['john', 'wells', 5], ['ryan', 'love', 0] ]
```

I want to only print out the names with 0 points scored in them, e.g. only print out `[Chris Jenkins 0]` and `[Ryan Love 0 ]`.

Comment: tried to use an if statement but couldnt really develop it

Comment: Update the question with your attempt that didn't work.

Comment: also, you could start voting/accepting answers - your last question got lots of answers, none of which you accepted.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/182887

Answer (score 2):

```
>>>[item for item in list1 if item[2]==0]

ans:-
[['chris', 'jenkins', 0], ['ryan', 'love', 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
for e in list1:
    if e[2] == 0:
        print e
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it actually since you don't need to print/load the whole thing into memory at once

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from itertools import ifilterfalse
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> list(ifilterfalse(itemgetter(2), list1))
[['chris', 'jenkins', 0], ['ryan', 'love', 0]]
```

Comment: this is fun but probably slower than the list comp